# Combining Two Single Column Queries, but keeping the columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to write a test database for a school project use sqlite. I have a table of Distributors

```
Distributors
Name               Address
'Distributor 1'    'Some Address'
'Distributor 2'    'Some Address'
....               .......
```

Another table of Books

```
BOOK
ISBN              Title            Other Columns ....
93281418414       'Some Title'
91231913532       'Other Title'
......            .......
```

I have a final table Distributor_Book

```
DISTRIBUTOR_BOOK
D_NAME                    ISBN
'Name of Distributor'     19204958052
```

I want a script that

```
SELECT ISBN FROM BOOK ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 20;
SELECT NAME FROM DISTRIBUTORS LIMIT 20;
```

Combines them together in the following way:

```
NEW TABLE
D_NAME         ISBN
'Dist. Name'   845829534   
..... X20
```

Then set this table to the DISTRIBUTOR_BOOK table. What is the correct tool for the job?

Comment: That would be a JOIN. The most basic SQL construct. Please take a SQL tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a school project, your data won't be too big.  You can do something like this:

```
insert into distributor_book (name, isbn)
    select d.name, b.isbn
    from books b cross join
         distributors d
    order by rand()
    limit 20;
```

I would only recommend this for small'ish tables -- no more than a few hundred rows.

Comment: Gordon, this works well but, I was more wondering how to do this but have the distributors be static. I apologize if my question is unclear. So I have 20 total distributors defined now and want to have a random isbn assigned to each of them.

Comment: Gordon, I ended up just using distinct keyword. Thank you for the working example, it helped me understand better how a join works.